# Cut text in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table:

```
Names
id | name    | text
1  | Mr Paul | aaaa
2  | Mr Marc | bbb
3  | Mr John | ccc
```

How can i  remove prefix "**Mr** " with SQL?

Comment: Do you want it to be invisible in a selection query, or do you want to update your table?

Comment: i want update my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer,

MySQL [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function do the task

```
UPDATE table
   SET name = REPLACE(name, 'Mr ', '') 
WHERE name LIKE 'Mr %'
```

It updates all names which begins with `Mr` suffix

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function.

```
 SELECT REPLACE(name, 'Mr ', '' ) FROM Names;
```

In order to update table do:

```
 UPDATE Names set name = REPLACE(name, 'Mr ', '' );
```

Little comment on optimization of this task: as stated in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16561068/2319383), you can achieve that with `SUBSTRING` function - this approach might be faster if you know that **every** row starts with `Mr` - DB engine does not have to look for `Mr` string (which consumes some time) but arbitrary cuts first 4 letters.

**Combo solution** (matches only `Mr` at the beginning but uses faster `SUBSTRING` instead of `REPLACE`):

```
UPDATE Names SET name = SUBSTRING(name FROM 4) WHERE name LIKE 'Mr %';
```

Comment: How about `name=Mr BlahMr Blah`?

Comment: you have to put `WHERE` condition in the query, otherwise things will happen like @Amir said. check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REPLACE`, although note that it will find instances ANYWHERE in the field, and not just at the beginning.

e.g.

```
select replace(x.Name, 'Mr ', '')
from
(select 'Mr Smith' as name
union select 'Mr Jones') as x;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name FROM 4) AS newname;
```